# Forma do usuário incluir páginas novas em um site sem programação

Tags: php, mysql

Assim como no WordPress tem a opção de criação, edição, exibição e edição das paginas

Sei que posso usar o WP, mas por aprendizado gostaria de fazer programando.

Estou tentando desenvolver uma função no meu painel que dever ter a opção criar página, ao ser clicado nessa opção ele me trás o campo `input type=text` para colocar o título da pagina,  o editor (o tinyMCE ou CKEditor), como o da imagem:
[image: add pagina]

Por exemplo: nessa área do WP tem a opção de edição e exclusão

[image: Opções]

Esses prints são do Wordpress.

No back-end, como fazer está codificação: sei que essas informações quando passadas são enviadas para o banco quando é gerado. Também tenho a opção criar um menu, fica tudo lincado.

Front-end, quando o cliente acessa o site lá esta o menu e quando clicado no menu aparece o conteúdo que é resgatado do banco.

Nesse processo todo eu sei fazer a página na administração pra salvar, editar e excluir, fazer os menus e lincá-los para o banco.

O problema é justamente do outro lado. Como eu faço para exibir esses arquivos e menus no template para o usuário? Exemplo:

`index.php?page=home`, `index.php?page=empresa` e `index.php?page=sobre` `index.php?page=contato?` (essas páginas existem).

Vamos supor que meu cliente tem o site da forma acima (ele não sabe programar uma linha de código) e ele quer criar uma página no site, por exemplo, para que fique assim: `index.php?page=galeria`, daí ele vai na administração e cria, pra depois aparecer a página e o respectivo menu que ele criou.

Eu preciso fazer uma função de loop que, "eu acho", fica verificando no banco direto pra sempre que tiver um novo menu na tabela menu(por exemplo) ele faça a exibição na `nav` do site, com uma condicional para só exibir se este menu tiver um conteúdo e este referência a algum conteúdo (seria o conteúdo da página) de que irá imprimir na tela para o usuário.

É isso que o Wordpress faz, correto? Como faz essa codificação? Tenho a lógica só não estou sabendo usá-la.

Eu estou confuso em como fazer pra exibir esse conteúdo (da nova página do exemplo que dei acima) formatado na tela para o usuário assim como as demais páginas que já tinha no site.

Comment: +1 pela atitude ("`mas por aprendizado gostaria de fazer programando.`")

Answer (score 2):

Bom, vamos ver se é isso que você quer...

você terá um DB assim (+-):

```
    //tabela paginas:
    //(id, nome, conteudo);
```

quando ele inserir uma nova página:

```
    //(1, galeria, conteudo1);
```

no index você pode fazer assim:

```
    <?php 

    $get_page = $_GET['page'];

    if(isset($get_page)){


    $selecionaPagina = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM paginas WHERE nome = '$get_page'");
    while($paginaConteudo = mysql_fetch_array($selecionaPagina)){

    }


    ?>

    // ai você faz o loop

    <div><?php echo $paginaConteudo['conteudo']; ?></div>

    <?php } ?>
```

ja no menu, você teria que fazer a mesma coisa, mas selecionando apenas as páginas com conteúdo

```
    <?php

    $selecionaPagina = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM paginas WHERE NOT conteudo = ''");
    while($paginaConteudo = mysql_fetch_array($selecionaPagina)){

    // ai você faz o loop

    <ul>

    <li><?php echo $paginaConteudo['nome']; ?></li>

    </ul>
```

para as páginas estáticas, ou você altera ao invés de index.php?page=contato para contato.php ou você cria arrays delas e faz uma verificação inicial no index. Tipo, se existir o $_GET['page'] e ele for = a contato: include("contato.php");

espero ter ajudado

Comment: Vou testar. obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Você deve trabalhar bem na estrutura do seu banco de dados pra ter um resultado legal, de fácil implementação e manutenção. Aqui estou ilustrando uma modelagem simples porém poderosa.

Basta estudar bem a modelagem, e realizar as consultas corretamente. Para a exibição do conteúdo você deve ter uma página que sempre busque pela "página" desejada e exiba o conteúdo da mesma com um `echo`.

---

### Modelagem de Banco

Tabela de menus (**navs**)

- id (único, auto_increment)
- nome (NOT NULL)
- descricao
- slug (único NOT NULL)
- ativo (1 - Ativo, 0 - Inativo, Default 0)
- id_menu (chave estrangeira).

**Registros**

```
(1, 'Home', 'Página inicial', 'home', 1, 1)
(2, 'Contato', 'Página de contatos', 'contato', 1, 1)
(3, 'Site map', 'Mapa do site (menu do rodapé do site)', 'site-map', 1, 2)
(4, 'Contato', 'Página de contatos (menu do rodapé do site)', 'contato', 1, 2)
```

**OBS: O campo `slug` é o que você vai passar nos links para a busca das páginas, então ele sempre deve ser único, como uma chave primária, e é recomendado indexa-lo.**

---

Tabela de grupo de menus (**menus**)

- id (único, auto_increment)
- descricao

**Registros**

```
(1, 'Menu Principal')
(2, 'Menu Rodapé')
```

---

Tabela de páginas (**pages**)

- id (único, auto_increment)
- title (NOT NULL)
- conteudo (NOT NULL)
- descricao
- keywords

**Registros**

```
(1, 'Home', '<p>Conteúdo da página</p>','Essa é a página inicial do site','página, inicio, home, site, foo, bar')
(2, 'Contato', '<p>Página de contato</p>','Essa é a página de contato do site','página, contato, contact, site, foo, bar')
(3, 'Site Map', '<p>Mapa do site</p>','Essa é a página com o mapa do site','página, map, site map, mapa do site, mapa, site, foo, bar')
```

---

Tabela de relacionamento entre menus e páginas (uma página pode ter vários menus, mas um menu apenas uma vez) (**navs_pages**)

- id_nav
- id_page

**Registros**

```
(1,1) // Menu principal -> Página Inicial
(2,2) // Menu principal -> Página Contato
(3,3) // Menu rodapé -> Site Map
(4,2) // Menu rodapé -> Página Contato
```

---

### Busca para os menus

```
$sql = "SELECT n.* FROM navs n WHERE n.id_menu = 1 AND n.ativo = 1;"; // Menu Princial
$sql = "SELECT n.* FROM navs n WHERE n.id_menu = 2; AND n.ativo = 1"; // Menu Rodapé

// Aqui você tem a lista dos menus é só trabalhar neles para montar o HTML
```

---

### Busca para as páginas

```
$page = (isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 'home');

$sql = "SELECT p.* 
        FROM navs n
           INNER JOIN navs_pages np ON (np.id_nav = n.id)
              INNER JOIN pages p ON (p.id = np.id_page)
        WHERE n.slug = '{$page}'"

// Executa essa consulta SQL e da um echo do conteúdo no local desejado
```

Comment: Boa dica vou tentar implementar, duvidas posto.

Comment: @Obrigado!pela dica.

Comment: Beleza, eu fiz os SQL na mão aqui e não testei, então se der algum problema e tu não tiver conseguindo resolver posta ai que a gente te ajuda. Se tu conseguir implementar e achar que essa é a pergunta mais adequada marca como aceita. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Deixa eu ver se eu entendi, você quer fazer uma aplicação *web* que cria e gerencia conteúdo, um CMS no caso.

Olha, se for isso, existem alguns materiais que podem ajudar você. Pesquisando rápido no Google achei esse, também em PHP:

[CMS com CakePhp](http://blog.erikfigueiredo.com.br/como-criar-um-cms-completo-com-cakephp-parte-1-instalando-configurando-e-deixando-seguro/)

O interessante desse artigo é que além de usar PHP, ele usa um *framework* para trabalhar com MVC, o que facilitaria sua codificação.

O que você está querendo fazer consiste basicamente em armazenar o HTML que o usuário digitar ou seu editor gerar no banco de dados, e em um *script* PHP, via **`$_GET['paginaexemplo']`**, você carrega essas informações do banco e coloca em alguma parte do código mesclado de PHP com HTML, o que geraria o seu código abaixo, exemplo:
`index.php?page=home, index.php?page=empresa e index.php?page=sobre index.php?page=contato?` (essas páginas existem).

A vantagem de usar um *framework* PHP como o CakePhp é que ele oferece uma série de recursos que você não precisaria fazer.

Comment: Seria sim um gerenciamento de paginas, So que eu quero implementa no meu painel, no caso vamos supor que tenho o painel administrativo, com controle de usuario, postagem, novidades, newsletter ... e quero apenas implementar o sistema para gereciar minhas paginas(Criar, editar e excluir, pois a exibição será feita do lado cliente). Isso qeu que eu não to conseguindo fazer.